# Why does the difference of the off diagonal determine the direction of rotation of planar system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have a planar system of differential equations given by
$$
y'=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}y
$$
where the matrix has complex eigenvalues. There is a test that says that the difference of the off diagonal entries determines the direction of rotation for the plot of the vector field in that if $b-c>0$ then the rotation is clockwise, and if $b-c<0$, the rotation is counter-clockwise.

There's no explanation for this test, and it's taken as a black box in the course. Does anyone have an explanation for why this is true?

Answer (score 1):

The [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is given by

$$ \textbf{R} = \left[\matrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta} \right]$$

where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation, with respect to the $x$-axis. The rotation is counter-clockwise for $\theta > 0$ and vice-versa

If you compare that to the original matrix, $b-c = -2\sin\theta$. This is negative if $\theta > 0$

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to this differential equation are flow curves to the vector field $v=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}y$. The rotation of a vector field is measured by its [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)), and the curl of this vector field is $b-c$, as is easily checked.